# SQLite error says there is 'no such column' when that column does exist

Tags: sqlite

Absolute beginner here.

I am creating a SQLite db for family NFL picks.  I have created a "`Results`' table for each game of last season and have uploaded the full 2023 schedule.  There are columns for scores, but I left these out to enter later.

I started to enter in the scores from Week 1 of last season, as though the week had just completed.  This is to mimic what I hope to do next season, week by week.  When I entered in the AwayScore and HomeScore columns, the SQLite error message "An error occurred while committing the data: no such column: AwayScore" is returned.

The full schema, and Results table are below, snipped from SQLite Studio.

[image: Results table columns]

[image: Schema]

I have tried several things:

- Renaming the column as there might be an extra character.
- Changing the Team IDs to include single quotes, then re-uploading the schedule .csv file
- Deleting the AwayScore column, and then seeing that the error does not happen to the HomeScore column.  I then added back in the AwayScore column.  The db accepted data twice, then again returned the error.  This is shown in the view of the data below.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Data entered into first three rows]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) both apply here. Also, your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in _SQLite Studio_ - have you tried using a different SQLite editor?

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try it in db browser or at terminal.